# Print Group Header on Pages Containing only Group Footers

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2010

I am using crystal reports with Visual Studio 2010.  This who problem arose because I want to append CrystalReports to eachother so they can print as one document, whether as a pdf or to a printer.  Hence I am stuck using SubReports and Groups to achieve this.

I am using SubReports and have Group Headers (GH) set to repeat on every page, as Page Headers do not work with SubReports.  I then have Group Footers (GF) that are supposed to display after all of my data in the details section.

**My problem is that for pages containing only GF(s) the GH do not display.**

It will happen most of the time but not all of the time that my GF not fit on the last page of my Details Section.

[I have tried this](http://scn.sap.com/thread/1497629).  Recreating my GH in a GF section, however PageHeaders do not work in SubReports and they only display on the first page.  So showing/supressing a GF section with  `Shared numberVar X` doesn't seem like it will work.

***Edit For Additional Clarification**

I am trying to print 4 reports or any combination of those 4 reports.  The reports being PackingSlip1, PackingSlip2 (Duplicate of PackingSlip1), PurchaseOrder, ReceivingReport.  So I might be printing PackingSlip1 and PurchaseOrder but not the other two.  Next time something different.

I initially had one of each of these Reports as SubReports in separate Group Footers.  I was grouping based upon the PurchaseOrderNumber (PONum).  I was sending a single PONum Parameter to my Main Report as well as Boolean Variables of whether each report type should print.  Each SubReport has a Parameter field and I use Subreport Links to send the PONum to each report.  I am not printing out data for groups of Purchase Order Numbers, I am only printing a different combination of reports for a single PONum, which ultimately will be based upon user input.

Each SubReport has a Header with Information that should repeat on each page. Such as the PONum and Page M of N.  I had several other group headers that were subressed unless PageNumber = 1, however this isn't relevant to the current problem.  Then I had in the details section of the SubReport the line items for that particular PONum the user was generating the report for.  Finally I was using GroupFooter sections to Print a Dollar Value Summary, area for signatures, etc.  I only want this to show up once at the end.  I am not using Page Footers because they are not required.

I also wanted to point out that each SubReport needs to have its own PageNumbering which I had placed in the GroupHeader of the SubReport which so far as worked fine but may impact any potential solution.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know where you have place sub report but in this case approach should be create the GH in main report above the sub report and write a suppress condition in main report GH that if there is only GF in sub report then main report GH should display.

Comment: I am not sure how to indicate to the Main Report that a page on my subreport only contains the footer information, but no detail information.  Perhaps a Subvar in first Group Footer Section of the subreport and the TotalPageCount to the Main Report?

Comment: Then do one thing instead of displaying GH in sub report, supress GH in subreport completely and just display the GH in main report. In this case irrespective of data in subreport you can see the GH